# SQL Server Mangament Studio 2008 unable to connect to SSIS packages on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssis

I get an "Class not registered" error whenever I attempt to connect to the integration services on sql server 2005 from within SQL Managment Studio 2008.

Is there a workaround? or do I have to downgrade to SQL managment studio 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install SSMS 2005 (I have both installed for example)

It's a known issue reported on [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/363922/connect-to-ssis-service-on-machine-servername-failed-class-not-registered)

Answer (score 0):

you can have them installed side by side, I have the same thing for things like that..Also have BIDS 2005 and 2008 side by side

Comment: Of course you will have less trouble if you install the older one first!